# How to TAB through TextBoxes in a ListView

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, textbox

Ok I have a ListView that has 2 GridViewColumns one displaying a number and one containing a TextBox
My Problem is I want to be able to Tab through all the TextBoxes I have in the GridViewColumn. 
With the attached Property KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation I achieve almost what i want.
What i achieve is :
**first TAB - whole first ListViewItem focused

second TAB - first TextBox focused

third TAB - whole second ListViewItem focused

fourth TAB - second TextBox focused**

What i want is
**first TAB - first TextBox focused

second TAB - second TextBox focused**

```
    <ListView KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="Continue" Name="TheLabelListView" >
                            <ListView.ItemContainerStyle >
                                    <EventSetter Event="Selected" Handler="ItemSelected" /></Style>
                            </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                            <ListView.View>
                                <GridView x:Name="GridViewSmall"  >
                                    <GridViewColumn  Header="#" Width="20"  DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding SelectorIndexNumber}" />
                                    <GridViewColumn  Header="Selector" Width="175">
                                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                            <DataTemplate>
                                                <TextBox Name="SelectorTextBox"  Text="{Binding SelectorName}"  />                                                    
                                            </DataTemplate>
                                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                    </GridViewColumn>
                                </GridView>
                            </ListView.View>
                        </ListView>
```

This code was given to me by H.B. . It is supposed to execute when a ListViewÍtem is selected and finds the TextBox and focuses it. Somehow it still doesnt select the TextBox everytime allthough when this method is executed bool TextBoxgotFocus is always true.

```
 private void ItemSelected(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var item = sender as ListViewItem;
        TextBox h = (FindNamedChild(item, "SelectorTextBox") as TextBox);
        bool TextBoxgotFocus = h.Focus();
    }

    public static object FindNamedChild(DependencyObject container, string name)
    {
        if (container is FrameworkElement)
        {
            if ((container as FrameworkElement).Name == name) return container;
        }
        var ccount = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(container);
        for (int i = 0; i < ccount; i++)
        {
            var child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(container, i);
            var target = FindNamedChild(child, name);
            if (target != null)
            {
                return target;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The problem is that for each item in the list view, you have two tab stops: the item itself and the text box.  You want to set `KeyboardNavigation.IsTabStop` to `false` for the items themselves.  Just set that in your item's style.

```
<ListView KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="Continue" Name="TheLabelListView">
    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style>
            <Setter Property="KeyboardNavigation.IsTabStop" Value="False" />
        </Style>
    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>

    <!-- etc... -->
</ListView>
```

Comment: I recently faced exactly the same issue. But your answer did not help. I have found out that listView items with no text boxes (no tabStops in them) crushes whole listView tab navigation. In other words eveything is ok only when each list item has at least one tabstop inside and in that case - yes - you just need to set no tabstop for item container to get it done well. but what if some items acts like headers? please help.