# Keyboard access for GridViewColumnHeaders?

Tags: wpf, xaml, gridview, gridviewcolumn

A ListView requirement we have is that the column headers be accessible by keyboard, which doesn't happen with the default ListView. For example:

```
    <StackPanel x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <ListView HorizontalAlignment="Left" KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="Local">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView >
                <GridViewColumn Header="Header _1" KeyboardNavigation.TabIndex="0"/>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Header _2" KeyboardNavigation.TabIndex="1"/>
                <GridViewColumn Header="header _3" KeyboardNavigation.TabIndex="2"/>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
        <ListViewItem Content="I'm the first item" />
        <ListViewItem Content="I'm the second item" />
    </ListView>
    <Button Content="I can also get focus" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,27,0,0"/>
</StackPanel>
```

The access keys show for the headers, but they don't get keyboard focus. The TabIndex and TabNavigation I added from reading this question:
[tabbing to TextBoxes in column headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7465151/how-to-tab-through-textboxes-in-a-listview)

What do I need to do to make the GridViewColumnHeaders keyboard accessible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Someone internal had the solution. In the GridViewColumnHeader ControlTemplate, set the ContentPresenter to be Focusable=true, like this:

```
            <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentPresenter"
                Style="{StaticResource ListViewContentPresenterStyle}" 
                ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" 
                SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"
                RecognizesAccessKey="True"
                Focusable="True"
                Grid.Column="1">
```

Also, set the ListView KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation=Local.